# Get file list from google drive public folder shared by link via API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm trying to create script to download all files from another user shared folder in google drive using rest api. If i'm right, there are two variants:

1. Using drive.children.list, with folder ID
2. Using drive.files.list, with search query like 'FOLDER_ID in parents'

But both of this variants returning only files which were once opened by my google account in browser. If I open file in browser - this file will appear in results of API calls.

Folder is shared for anyone, who has link.

Where is the problem, how I can list all files in folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not give us any info about the SCOPE, I am wild-guessing that it may be your problem. You probably have FILE scope, instead of DRIVE.

Also, I would recommend to test these things with ['TryIt!' here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list). You can quickly modify both scopes and queries there.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for answer, it helped me to discover problem - i used incorrect scope variable from old script. Trivial bugs are most difficult to discover =(

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug/quirk in the Drive API, though there is an easy workaround. If you call files.update with 'addParents=root' it'll add the shared folder under 'My Drive'. This has the effect of making the files part of your corpus and they'll appear in results.